# PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK

Tags: gnupg

How could I read a message wich is codated with Version: GnuPG v2.0.17 (MingW32)
This is how the message starts.

```
-----BEGIN PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
Version: GnuPG v2.0.17 (MingW32)

[crypted message]

-----END PGP PUBLIC KEY BLOCK-----
```

How can I read the message?

Comment: What email client are you using?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is not an encrypted message, but somebody is sending you his public key (which you could use to *send* an encrypted message to him.

You could read it by importing to GnuPG. Save everything of the public key block (including the start and end lines with their dashes) into a text file, and import it from the command line:

```
gpg --import thefile.asc
```

File name and extension do not matter, `.asc` is best practice. Gnupg will now print what key it imported.

Comment: So that is a code(key) which i use to talk to that person in encrypted messages. So the GnuPG is a program that allowes me to see that key and send him a crypted message to? if i understood corectly how i could get that program? please help waiting feedback:)

Comment: As you tagged the question with [tag:gnupg] I expected you know at least a little bit about it and did not explain further. GnuPG is a free and open source implementation of OpenPGP, one common standard for mail encryption (and some other stuff). It uses private/public key pairs for encryption (public for encrypting, private for decrypting). Explaining OpenPGP is far beyond scope of a superuser question, it is a rather complex and huge matter. I'd recommend to start reading a little bit on [Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GnuPG).

Comment: Iam sorry i don't have any type of minimal information about this.I've read on this site about GnuPG and many others articles but i didn't understood very much.All i know is that i need help to read that message and to know how to write thoose types of messages (is very important) .Iam also a girl and if u could help me like explain to me like a child maybe will have a change, and i will be very greatefull to you.Maybe we could swich email also if this site allowes us to do that and talk there. thank you for the help you already gave me and have a great day!